# Even hub checkpoint as resiliency mechanism

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am reading data and processing it further. if processing fails, I will not call checkpoint function. I hope that not checkpointing will stop further processing of events until issue is fixed. Is checkpointing sufficient for resiliency or I need to implement something like dead blob processor to provide failure handling?

Comment: Can you provide the name of the package that you're using and its version?   I also don't understand what "stop further processing" would mean if you're simply not calling to checkpoint.   Can you expand on your scenario?

Comment: @JesseSquire I want to [re]use event hub as dead blob processor i.e. I do not want to process data if I find any issue with current EventData I read.

What if I will not checkpoint after reading from event hub. Is it guaranteed that I will come back to same EventData? Or client will continue to read next data until client-side failure.

Comment: I'm still not following the end-to-end scenario, but as a high-level concept, I agree with Peter.  Your code is expected to handle each event in sequence and if you're ultimately unable to do so, any dead-lettering is an application responsibility.  Depending on what package you're using, there may be considerations or suggestions that can be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is checkpointing sufficient for resiliency

No not really. The processing will continue until the process hosting the processing logic stops. Say for example you have an azure funtion processing the message this will go on.

What does happen that in the event of a function restart (or whatever process you use to handle event hub messages) the function will start processing messages from the moment of the last checkpoint. Probably not what you want because the messages that caused a failure in the past will be processed again and probably fail again.

There is no dead lettering or retry mechanism out of the box, you will need to define that logic yourself.

So, TL;DR: the checkpoint its only purpose is to tell the processing logic where to start processing message from the backlog.

Comment: can we use same dead letter mechanism to store event in case of event hub failure? If we rely on checkpointing to take effect, do we have to restart the event hub consumer?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with the event hub failure. If the event hub service is down, message producers won't be able to push events and consumers will resume after the service is restored and start from the latest checkpoint.

Comment: My service reads from event hub and write to target event hub. If target is completely down, then I will not checkpoint on source event hub. But since consumer (My service) will continue to read events, do I have to restart my service so that it will start reading from last checkpoint? also since service will continue to read data, I will have lot of duplicate events whenever I will restart the service.